# Do a test connection from nodejs to oracle database

Tags: node.js, oracle, electron, node-oracledb

I have to test oracle DB from my nodejs application but does not show up any result
following is what I have tried

Have also attached screenshot of application frontend from whjere the testconnection is done

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb'); 
$(document).on('click', '#sourceOracle #testcon', function(event) {
          runTest();
        })
            async function runTest() {
              let conn;
            
              try {
                conn = await oracledb.getConnection({ user: 'OT', password: 'mypassword', connectString: 'localhost:1521/orcl' });
                console.log(conn)
                const result = await conn.execute(
                  'select current_timestamp from dual'
                );
            
                console.log(result);
              } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
              } finally {
                if (conn) {
                  try {
                    await conn.close();
                  } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

I get below error

```
ORA-24550: signal received: Unhandled exception: Code=c0000005 Flags=0
```

result of conn

```
Connection {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, _dbObjectClasses: {…}}
_dbObjectClasses:
__proto__: Object
_events:
No properties
_eventsCount: 0
_maxListeners: undefined
action: (...)
callTimeout: (...)
clientId: (...)
clientInfo: (...)
currentSchema: (...)
dbOp: (...)
module: (...)
oracleServerVersion: (...)
oracleServerVersionString: (...)
stmtCacheSize: (...)
tag: (...)
__proto__: EventEmitter[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Hoatname should be localhost

Comment: @Tejash have give localhost

Comment: But in screenshot it is localhost:1521/orcl so asked you to change it to localhost only

Comment: I just hardcoded value for now in my code

Comment: I am not using the values from screenshot ..just the testconnection button there

Comment: any solution will be helpfull

Comment: Try using Oracle client 19c (which will let you connect to Oracle DB 11.2 or later) and clean up your environment (i.e. remove older versions - do a thorough search)

Comment: The error you received indicates what is most likely a problem with your code. If you can rule out any issues with your code or your environment, then the recommended action is to contact Oracle Support.